# Menu out of right boundary but not left

Tags: html, css

So I have a navigation menu. `nav.png` is empty space and `nav1.png nav2.png nav3.png nav4.png` are actual buttons like `home`,`about us`, etc.

I have the following code:

```css
#navigation_bar {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu_btn {
  display: table-cell;
}
.menu_btn img {
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation_bar">
  <div class="menu_btn">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q5bs.png">
  </div>
  <div class="menu_btn">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxDQj.png">
  </div>
  <div class="menu_btn">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwmkn.png">
  </div>
  <div class="menu_btn">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRpbK.png">
  </div>
  <div class="menu_btn">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GksMc.png">
  </div>
  <div class="menu_btn">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q5bs.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

With the above code I get this

[image]

As you see the menu ISN'T centered. I want the menu to be in the centre. the bar goes out of window on the right side. but on the left side it maintains a margin of few pixels...

I want it to go out of window on BOTH sides so it kind of appears as a black line throughout the page.

Also, my `nav.png` is a long image (width-wise).

here are the pngs

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hard to say without access to the pngs.

Comment: In this case you almost certainly want a tiling background instead of your wide one. An <img> will push out the width of the table and the document. (You probably have a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of your document.) You could stretch your image using width:100% or use `overflow-x: hidden;' on your html-tag (it might not even work on tables), but even so that smells pretty bad and can lead to other unexpected page behavior. Go with a background-image!

Comment: I've added the `pngs` @MikeLoffland.

Comment: @MikeLoffland is right, I tried it here and it does center, I assume the images are causing some issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/a2jmnmy3/

I would also strongly suggest not doing it this way - images for menu items is generally a bad idea (for readability, zoom etc etc). If you need the font or look it can be achieved with CSS and web-fonts or even something like http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Happy to help but need the images.

Comment: Also see if `html,body{margin:0; padding:0}` fixes your left side margin.

Comment: @ippi that DOES make both sides go out of window. However, it still isn't centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Let's modernise!

Let's make this with pure CSS:

[image: Mirror Nav]

### Background CSS gradients and no images, mirrored using pseudo elements

We can achieve this even more easily by using a linear gradient background and no images at all.

- The background is created by the linear-gradient.
- The font can be changed in the CSS if desired.
- The text is vertically centered with the `line-height: 40px` (matching the height of the nav)
- The text is horizontally centered with `text-align: center` on the nav

Using the `data-*` and pseudo elements, we can even provide a mirror image underneath *with pure CSS*.

Main benefits:

- Link text is easily archived by search engines, improving SEO and link text is easily read by screen-readers
- Gradient and links can easily be changed without editing images

#### Complete Example

CSS gradients [are supported IE10 +](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) and IE 6 - 9 are supported using a filter. Ensure that there are no gaps between the opening and closing `<a>`. [This prevents an inline gap](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

```css
nav {
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;/*Non supporting browsers*/
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);/*CSS Standard*/
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /*IE6 - 9*/
  line-height: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 620px;
    position: relative;
}
nav::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 0) 0%, rgba(44, 44, 44, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);/*CSS Standard*/
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
nav a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-right: solid 1px #FFF;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a:first-child {
  border-left: solid 1px #FFF;
}
nav a:hover {
background: #F00;  
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(248,80,50,1) 0%,rgba(241,111,92,1) 50%,rgba(246,41,12,1) 51%,rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%,rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
}
nav a::before {
content: attr(data-mirror); 
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #000;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.2;
  pointer-events: none;
}
nav a:hover::before { 
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#" data-mirror="Home">Home</a><a href="#" data-mirror="Categories">Categories</a><a href="#" data-mirror="Create">Create</a><a href="#" data-mirror="Upload">Upload</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: wow Amazing !!! Just one thing. When I change the `padding` inside `nav a` why does the white vertical lines' height increases?

Comment: Now that i think about it i remember why i used images. It was because when the mouse rolls over a button, the color changes from black to say red...

Comment: @Matin - Now updated with a red hover gradient background. You can generate your own CSS gradients easily here: [gradient link](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: simply amazing. I'm sorry I'm a beginner in CSS

Comment: @Matin - No worries dude! There is always something to learn :) I have also added a slight highlight to the reflection of the hovered link using `nav a:hover::before`

Answer (score 2):

Take the background-image approach.

```css
#navigation_bar {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q5bs.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  text-align:center;  
}

.menu_btn {
  display:inline-block;
}

.menu_btn img {
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>GETTING STARTED WITH BRACKETS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <img src="images/logo/logo.png">
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div id="navigation_bar">
            <div class="menu_btn"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxDQj.png" /></div>
            <div class="menu_btn"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwmkn.png" /></div>
            <div class="menu_btn"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRpbK.png" /></div>
            <div class="menu_btn"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GksMc.png" /></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. The margin however is ruined now. i think the menu button have margins. I tried putting `margin: 0;` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand your end objective. What margin is ruined? How so?